# Android markers without using Google maps

Tags: android, google-maps

I am very new to android, and I basically have almost no experience. Recently my client got an idea where he wants to have a custom map (in .png/.jpg/.jpeg format) on which, using GPS only, will be displayed his location using a marker, and location where he is supposed to get. Those two markers have to be connected with a "path", that will be like some sort of navigation from one marker to another. One of the requests is that it must be done without any usage of Google maps. My question here is - is that even possible to be done like this?

The only idea that I got is to get coordinate from GPS, make a proportion pixels on the image to coordinates and put a marker on where the user is supposed to be. Is there a better option than this?

Comment: What Map service are you using instead of GoogleMaps ?

Comment: It should be just a picture of a map. Soooo, I guess none

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try out this method in the below [link](http://www.maptiler.com/).
Which can turn your images into interactive map layers that can be displayed in websites, used in mobile phones, tablets, GPS devices, map mashups or opened in the desktop GIS software, Google Maps or Google Earth.

http://www.maptiler.com/

Comment: I have seen this, but unfortunately, it doesn't help, and I already have a map in form of a image on which markers should be placed automatically using GPS.